# Python Tkinter small window pops up momentarily before main window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5

Hello I am making a Python Tkinter GUI program but as I was making it I noticed that a small Tkinter window pops up then closes before the main window pops up.  It is very distracting and obviously something that you would have in a professional piece of software.  Here is an example of the problem:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title("My GUI")
app.iconbitmap(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Files\journalicon.ico")
app.resizable(0,0)

button = Button(text = "Text")
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

The `iconbitmap` option was something I found from another stack overflow page and used it.  If you know of a better option I would appreciate the help. I am quite lost and would really appreciate any answers.

Comment: That code doesn't do anything but create a single window. Post a _complete_, _minimal_ program that illustrates the problem ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Most likely the problem is that you're creating some other widget before this code gets executed.

Comment: You're saying that _exact_ program runs, but causes a blank window to appear briefly? That seems impossible. The error in calling `iconbitmap` should cause the entire program to stop running. How are you running this program?

Comment: Yes that exact program.  I created it to use as an example for this question and it does the same thing as a more complex program.  I run my python script through Notepad++.  However I just tried running the file directly through the command line and had the same result.  Would you like me to do a screen capture and make a video showing the issue?

Comment: I also had the same issue using your code in the Python IDE, soo.

Comment: I think I finally figured out the root of the problem.  It pops up the first momentary window when `iconbitmap` is not placed in app.  So instead of my original code `app.iconbitmap(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Files\journalicon.ico")` you need to do `app.iconbitmap(app, r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Files\journalicon.ico")`.  Thank you everyone for your help answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app = Tk()
app.title("My GUI")
app.iconbitmap(app, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Files\icon.ico")
app.resizable(0,0)

app.mainloop()
```

You let tkinter know that the definition for things inside the window have stopped by calling mainloop. I have defined the window for the iconbitmap when it is called, using "(app, .."

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not what `mainloop` is for, and `iconbitmap` takes a single argument, not two.

Comment: I tried this but got an error.  Then realized that the error was I needed double backslashes where I had the single backslash.  I am not sure if that was the problem before but it seems to be working now. I got my code from somewhere else so I didn't know if that was the proper syntax.  Thank you for the answer

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused: yes, I've tried it. Have you? You'll get  a "wrong # args" error on the call ti `iconbitmap`. There's also the problem that `iconbitmap` does not accept a .ico file.

Comment: @MarkyPython Ah, I didn't spot that double backslash error, I only checked the ICO in the current directory.

Comment: My solution works perfectly for me, we must be running different versions of tkinter. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=59190977235800788354 I have used an example ICO which I created in a previous project.

Comment: For Windows' paths, use a) forward slashes (easiest), b) `r` prefix, or c) double slashes, but never single backslashes without `r` prefixes.  You may get away with the latter, but only until you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it's caused by a delay in executing code before the window is drawn.  The solution is to set the window size before doing anything else. Move app.resizable(0,0) up, and the problem goes away.

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.resizable(0,0) 
app.title("My GUI")
app.iconbitmap(r"C:\some_random_icon.ico")

button = Button(text = "Text")
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

In my case I had the *self.geometry()* command defined too low down, this should also be executed immediately after you initiate your app.

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('200x100')
#... add rest of code here.
```