# Python Tkinter- small window pops up momentarily before main window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825915/6282576) to create a simple window. When I run `python mainwindow.py`, a small window pops up briefly and closes right before *main window* (mostly to the **top left** corner of the screen). Here's a GIF demonstrating it:

[image: wtf]

Here's the code I've used (`mainwindow.py`):

```py
import tkinter as tk


def center(win, width, height):
    win.update_idletasks()
    x = (win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (width // 2)
    y = (win.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (height // 2)
    win.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}')


def main():
    width = 500
    height = 500

    main_window = tk.Tk()
    main_window.title('7Watchlist DataGrabber')
    main_window.iconbitmap(main_window, r'images\icon.ico')
    center(main_window, width, height)
    main_window.resizable(False, False)

    main_window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There is an exactly similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156037/python-tkinter-small-window-pops-up-momentarily-before-main-window) with an accepted answer. On it, OP [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156037/python-tkinter-small-window-pops-up-momentarily-before-main-window#comment56086264_34156037) in the comments:

> I think I finally figured out the root of the problem. [...] So instead of my original code `app.iconbitmap(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Files\journalicon.ico")` you need to do `app.iconbitmap(app, r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Files\journalicon.ico")` [...]

And the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158119/6282576) seems to indicate the same thing:

- To replace `app.iconbitmap(r'address')` with `app.iconbitmap(app, r'address')`.

But my code already uses `iconbitmap` in this format. So my question is: How can I get rid of this small window?

Comment: Remove `win.update_idletasks()`

Comment: @stovfl That worked! Why didn't you make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Feel free to write a answer to show you solution, refer to [Tkinter.Widget.update-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed the `bitmap = main_window` from `main_window.wm_iconbitmap(bitmap=None, default=None)` and seems like it solved the problem, I only set the default parameter. Though I'm on Mac OS and `iconbitmap` doesn't properly work like the icon doesn't show.

Also I ran it with `win.update_idletasks()` and still don't see the small window but you can give it a try by removing it.

[image]

I hope this helped you.