# Tkinter window not centering when adding window icon -Python

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

I have this problem that window is not place on the center of the screen when I add window icon thru root.iconbitmap("automation1.ico").

It randomly placed on the top left of the screen. Also observed that the window height was slightly changed automatically.

But when I removed the icon, and icon was set to tkinter's default icon, screen is centered on the screen.

I already tried different ICON sizes from 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 64x64 but still is not working.

Default tkinter icon - CENTERED:
[image]

With added icon. Size 24x24 - Random open on TOP LEFT:
[image]

Code used:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("KNS Machine Log Converter Ver.2.1")
#root.iconbitmap("pythontutorial-1-150x150.ico")
#root.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file="automation.png"))
root.resizable(False, False)

window_width = 1000
window_height = 480
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (window_width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (window_height/2)
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
```

Appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Have you done - `root.geometry(axb+c+d)`. Here `c` and `d` defines a fixed position. And `a` and `b` are the dimensions of the window

Comment: @PCM Yes, I'll already have that in my code. It centers the screen without the root.iconbitmap line. But when I add the icon it randomly opens on the top left screen.

Comment: What is the smallest icon size you can try?

Comment: @PCM I already tried different ICON sizes from 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 64x64. The same results.

Comment: When I run your code, I get a result similar to the one [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156037/python-tkinter-small-window-pops-up-momentarily-before-main-window). A small window appears in the upper left corner of the screen for a few seconds. After that, a window with the specified height and width appears in the center of the screen. This small window does not appear if I use `root.iconbitmap(root,"favicon.ico")` or add an icon after `root.geometry`. Maybe this has nothing to do with your problem, but you can experiment in this direction.

Comment: @8349697 Thank you so much. This definitely solve the issue. The flashing small window also disappeared during program start up.